# Как сделать border-image в форме волны (wave)?

Tags: html, css, border

Ребята как сделать так чтобы `border-image` был наоборот повернут вниз через `CSS` пытаюсь уже какой раз, не получается.
Должен быть как в картинке в приложении ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wave{
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.wave::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px -5px, transparent 12px, aquamarine 13px);
}
.wave::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image:
    radial-gradient(circle at 10px 15px, aquamarine 12px, transparent 13px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то так

```css
.wave{
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wave::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 10px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image:
radial-gradient(4px 5px at bottom, transparent 12px, aquamarine 13px);
}
.wave::after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image:
radial-gradient(circle at top, aquamarine 14px, transparent 12px);
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Можно просто развернуть и подогнать:

```css
body {
  background: red
}

.wave {
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  background: aquamarine;
}

.wave::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10px 0px, transparent 12px, aquamarine 13px);
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}

.wave::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -15px;
  right: 0;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  height: 15px;
  background-size: 40px 20px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at 10px 15px, aquamarine 12px, transparent 13px);
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}
```

```html
<div class="wave"></div>
```